# How do I submit the data of a form to an external url in Fancybox?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, fancybox

I have a form like this;

```
<form action="https://www.exampleurl.com" method="post" id="postForm">
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.hiddenField)
    <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This url "https://www.exampleurl.com" only allow POST..
When I click the btnSubmit I want to show datas on fancybox (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) which datas return from "https://www.exampleurl.com"..

I try a lot of things and I get this error; "localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: Try running your ajax in a server environment assuming that the (action) controller is within the same domain.

Comment: It is a bank url so I cant do it in the same domain..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a two-part issue here:

1) Since you're doing a form post, IF the form submitted correctly the user would be directed away from your site to https://www.exampleurl.com. You'd never catch the response, because the user will now be on whatever page is served by exmapleurl.com. If you'd like to be able to catch the response and keep the user on your site, you should use $.post to post data via ajax.

2) Many sites will not allow cross-domain posts for security reasons, hence the Access-Control error you're getting. If you either control the destination site or are working with an administrator there, you can ask them to update the access control policy on the web server to allow posts from your domain. If you have no ability to influence the other site's policy, then you're not going to be able to do what you're attempting no matter what.